# Hex to string, the python way, in powershell

Tags: python, powershell, hash, hex, hmac

A bit of a weird question perhaps, but I'm trying to replicate a python example where they are creating a HMAC SHA256 hash from a series of parameters.

I've run into a problem where I'm supposed to translate an api key in hex to ascii and use it as secret, but I just can't get the output to be the same as python.

```
>>> import hmac
>>> import hashlib
>>> apiKey = "76b02c0c4543a85e45552466694cf677937833c9cce87f0a628248af2d2c495b"
>>> apiKey.decode('hex')
'v\xb0,\x0cEC\xa8^EU$fiL\xf6w\x93x3\xc9\xcc\xe8\x7f\nb\x82H\xaf-,I['
```

If I've understood the material online this is supposed to represent the hex string in ascii characters.

Now to the powershell script:

```
$apikey = '76b02c0c4543a85e45552466694cf677937833c9cce87f0a628248af2d2c495b';

$hexstring = ""

for($i=0; $i -lt $apikey.Length;$i=$i+2){
    $hexelement = [string]$apikey[$i] + [string]$apikey[$i+1]
    $hexstring += [CHAR][BYTE][CONVERT]::toint16($hexelement,16)
}
```

That outputs the following:

```
v°,♀EC¨^EU$fiLöw?x3ÉÌè⌂
b?H¯-,I[
```

They are almost the same, but not quite and using them as secret in the HMAC generates different results. Any ideas?

> Stating the obvious: The key in this example is no the real key.

Update:
They look more or less the same, but the encoding of the output is different. I also verified the hex to ASCII in multiple online functions and the powershell version seems right.

Does anyone have an idea how to compare the two different outputs?

Update 2:
I converted each character to integer and both Python and Powershell generates the same numbers, aka the content should be the same.

Attaching the scripts

Powershell:

```
Function generateToken {

    Param($apikey, $url, $httpMethod, $queryparameters=$false, $postData=$false)


    #$timestamp = [int]((Get-Date -UFormat %s).Replace(",", "."))
    $timestamp = "1446128942"

    $datastring = $httpMethod + $url

    if($queryparameters){ $datastring += $queryparameters }
    $datastring += $timestamp
    if($postData){ $datastring += $postData }


    $hmacsha = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256

    $apiAscii = HexToString -hexstring $apiKey

    $hmacsha.key = [Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($apiAscii)
    $signature = $hmacsha.ComputeHash([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($datastring))
    $signature
}

Function HexToString {

    Param($hexstring)

    $asciistring = ""

    for($i=0; $i -lt $hexstring.Length;$i=$i+2){
        $hexelement = [string]$hexstring[$i] + [string]$hexstring[$i+1]
        $asciistring += [CHAR][BYTE][CONVERT]::toint16($hexelement,16)
    }

    $asciistring
}

Function TokenToHex {

    Param([array]$Token)

    $hexhash = ""

    Foreach($element in $Token){
        $hexhash += '{0:x}' -f $element
    }

    $hexhash
}


$apiEndpoint = "http://test.control.llnw.com/traffic-reporting-api/v1"
#what you see in Control on Edit My Profile page#
$apikey = '76b02c0c4543a85e45552466694cf677937833c9cce87f0a628248af2d2c495b';
$queryParameters = "shortname=bulkget&service=http&reportDuration=day&startDate=2012-01-01"
$postData = "{param1: 123, param2: 456}"

$token = generateToken -uri $apiEndpoint -httpMethod "GET" -queryparameters $queryParameters, postData=postData, -apiKey $apiKey
TokenToHex -Token $token
```

Python:

```
import hashlib
import hmac
import time
try: import simplejson as json
except ImportError: import json
class HMACSample:
        def generateSecurityToken(self, url, httpMethod, apiKey, queryParameters=None, postData=None):
                #timestamp = str(int(round(time.time()*1000)))
                timestamp = "1446128942"
                datastring = httpMethod + url
                if queryParameters != None : datastring += queryParameters
                datastring += timestamp
                if postData != None : datastring += postData
                token = hmac.new(apiKey.decode('hex'), msg=datastring, digestmod=hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()
                return token
if __name__ == '__main__':
        apiEndpoint = "http://test.control.llnw.com/traffic-reporting-api/v1"
        #what you see in Control on Edit My Profile page#
        apiKey = "76b02c0c4543a85e45552466694cf677937833c9cce87f0a628248af2d2c495b";
        queryParameters = "shortname=bulkget&service=http&reportDuration=day&startDate=2012-01-01"
        postData = "{param1: 123, param2: 456}"
        tool = HMACSample()
        hmac = tool.generateSecurityToken(url=apiEndpoint, httpMethod="GET", queryParameters=queryParameters, postData=postData, apiKey=apiKey)
        print json.dumps(hmac, indent=4)
```

apiKey with "test" instead of the converted hex to ASCII string outputs the same value which made me suspect that the conversion was the problem. Now I'm not sure what to believe anymore.

/Patrik

Comment: What output you want to get from your input data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ASCII encoding support characters from this code point range 0–127. Any character outside this range, encoded with byte 63, which correspond to `?`, in case you decode byte array back to string. So, with your code, you ruin your key by applying ASCII encoding to it. But if what you want is a byte array, then why do you do `Hex String -> ASCII String -> Byte Array` instead of just `Hex String -> Byte Array`?

Here is PowerShell code, which generate same results, as your Python code:

```
function GenerateToken {
    param($apikey, $url, $httpMethod, $queryparameters, $postData)

    $datastring = -join @(
        $httpMethod
        $url
        $queryparameters
        #[DateTimeOffset]::Now.ToUnixTimeSeconds()
        1446128942
        $postData
    )

    $hmacsha = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256

    $hmacsha.Key = @($apikey -split '(?<=\G..)(?=.)'|ForEach-Object {[byte]::Parse($_,'HexNumber')})

    [BitConverter]::ToString($hmacsha.ComputeHash([Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($datastring))).Replace('-','').ToLower()
}

$apiEndpoint = "http://test.control.llnw.com/traffic-reporting-api/v1"
#what you see in Control on Edit My Profile page#
$apikey = '76b02c0c4543a85e45552466694cf677937833c9cce87f0a628248af2d2c495b';
$queryParameters = "shortname=bulkget&service=http&reportDuration=day&startDate=2012-01-01"
$postData = "{param1: 123, param2: 456}"

GenerateToken -url $apiEndpoint -httpMethod "GET" -queryparameters $queryParameters -postData $postData -apiKey $apiKey
```

I also fix some other errors in your PowerShell code. In particular, arguments to `GenerateToken` function call. Also, I change ASCII to UTF8 for `$datastring` encoding. UTF8 yields exactly same bytes if all characters are in ASCII range, so it does not matter in you case. But if you want to use characters out of ASCII range in `$datastring`, than you should choose same encoding, as you use in Python, or you will not get the same results.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I realized that I only saw the \x__ encoding when running the code in the interpreter. However, my powershell script does not give the same characters everywhere. Updating the case.

Comment: You're a wizard, that solved it! And I learned something too. If you're ever in Stockholm I owe you  a few beers. :)